# Activity Indicator not showing on PDF uiwebview load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

i am developing a app with a uiwebview and in that webview i need to load a local pdf file when uiwebview calls a native method through java. and i am successful doing that but when i browse through webisete activity indicator shows well but when native function calls and i load pdf in uiwebview it doesnot shows while loading pdf from url. let me post my code here.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize webPage;
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
    return NO;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    webLink = @"http://url.com/m/";
    liNk = webLink;
    [webPage loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:liNk]]];
    webPage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //[[webPage.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setBounces:NO];
    [(UIScrollView*)[webPage.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [webPage addSubview:activity];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(loading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    webPage.delegate = self;
}
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"ios:"]) {
        // Call the given selector
        [self performSelector:@selector(webToNativeCall)];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;

}
- (void)webToNativeCall
{
        NSString *pdfurl = @"http://url.com/mypdf.pdf";
        NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pdfurl]];
        NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
        NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mypdf.pdf"];
        [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        // Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [webPage setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [webPage setDelegate:self];
        [webPage loadRequest:requestObj];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I didn't get complele flow of your code. But if you are using UIActivityIndicatorView, try [activity startAnimating]; to show activity indicator and [activity stopAnimating]; to stop

Comment: Thanks for replying. i did that but still not showing activity indicator i even tried to user status bar default indicator even that is not working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting and stoping activity indicator in UIWebViewDelegate methods

```
  #pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate -

-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType
{
    [activity startAnimating];

    if ([[[inRequest URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"ios:"]) 
    {
       // Call the given selector
       [self performSelector:@selector(webToNativeCall)];
       return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [activity stopAnimating];
}


-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [activity stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: ERROR : use of undeclared identifier 'request'

Comment: i use [activity startAnimating]; and [activity stopAnimating]; not its showing indicator only at the time when it is going to open pdf but what i need is to show indicator even when uiwebview is downloading pdf. anyways THANKS

Comment: "ERROR : use of undeclared identifier 'request' " corrected

Comment: add below delegate method also   -(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

Comment: still the same as i told in my last msg only show when pdf is going to open but i want to show when uiwebview downloads pdf. Thanks

Comment: "when uiwebview downloads pdf.". Is it downloaded a separate thread. Sorry as I didnt understand !!

Comment: as u can see in the code it is downloading pdf then loading it in uiwebview. loading in pdf part is showing indicator but when it is downloading pdf it does not.

Comment: You are telling about this  < NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:pdfurl]]; > . You can put start and stop activity indicator above and below. Or While loading the view in viewdidload you can download this pdf, in separate thread using GCD or NSOperationQueue, the application will be faster

Comment: "initWithContentsOfURL" is time intensive function, usually its better to be in separate thread than main thread. If you are new to Thread, NSOperationQueue etc you may find it little difficult. Application is only downloading mypdf and it is not of big size,then for time being you can adjust with indicator  by starting it above and stoping it below of this function. Hope this helps!!